# Showing UISearchController on UINavigationItem from background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, ios11

Using iOS 11 SDK, UISearchController newer appear if you want to show it from background thread:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.searchResultsController = [UITableViewController new];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsController];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"Do something in background");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
                self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to show it after background task completion?

**EDIT1:**
VC with search controller should't be initial VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works perfectly. Please make sure your device or your simulator version is greater or equal iOS 11 and you don't do anything else with `navigationItem`.

If you VC is pushed or presented from another viewController, put you code into `viewDidAppear`. It will work

Comment: Try my example code be opened by segue or presenting by other VC

Comment: @NikolayKrasnov you mean that your VC is pushed or presented from another viewController. Is it right?

Comment: Try to put your code into `viewDidAppear`. I have updated my answer, you can check again. @NikolayKrasnov

Comment: It will work. Thanks for help. Only for me this behaviour looks not intuitive and buggy?

Comment: @NikolayKrasnov can you explain your question more clearly? I don't understand what are you trying to ask.

Comment: I think the problem relate to `viewDidLoad` method but not manipulate UI from main thread. As you see,  you still can do it if you move all code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I want background task to be initiated earlier than viewDidAppear

Comment: if you don't want `searchBar` appears after VC appears. Just set `self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;` after you initialze `self.searchController` and do everything else in background normally.